# How to store where a new user was referred? Using Rails + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a rails app that uses devise. I'm curious to know, is it possible in the User table to somehow track where a new user came from, the HTTP referrer?

I'd like to know which came from Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google+ in order to track a viral loop.

Any ideas? Seen anyone do this? Possible? Where should this live in the rails app? Still very new. Thanks

Comment: When? When he landed to website and then registered or per any visit?

Comment: Anytime a new User.record is created

Comment: Is request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] not available locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be done like this. May require some tweaking and fixing but You'll get an idea
Make before filter for Application controller, you will call it for any action

```
def landing_filter
   if from_other_site(request.referrer) and !session[:referer].blank?
      session[:referer] = request.referrer #you don't want to delete first entrance 
   end
end
```

from_other_site should be the method which will check domain name in referrer url, if it match your then return `false`, otherwise `true`

in devise/registration/new.erb.html view add in form hidden field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :referrer, session[:referrer] %>
```

and don't forget to add migration with new database field for user

Comment: Thanks but any idea why the referre is not showing up on localhost? Does something disable referre locally?

Comment: Your browser should always send referrer except if you type url by hand in browser or initially open page, for instance, from browser bookmarks menu. To check how this example works, try to make post in Facebook with url `http://localhost:3000/your_controller/action` and check referrer url in log or debugger it should be the same as facebook page url where you clicked the link

Comment: Do you know how to implement from other site method?

Comment: I/m not sure what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

Save referer somewhere and after creating a user copy information to user table. Using session to save referer works but permanent cookies are better. Cookies can persist the information even when user closes browser and comes again in the next day.

```
# so basically in ApplicationContreller using before_filter
def referer_before_filter
  if cookies[:referer].blank?
    cookies.permanent[:referer] = request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] || 'none'
  end
end

# and in signup action somewhere else saving that information
@user.referer = cookies[:referer] # or maybe to some other table
```

Instead of modifying every action you can also use [rails sweepers/observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) to handle automatic saving every time an object is created.

A good gem to automatically save referer and other needed information is
https://github.com/holli/referer_tracking . You can choose do you want to save information manually or use sweepers to do saving automatically.