# How to get the referer url of a previous page in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I will try to put it in a simple way. I have a **Sign Up button** *(which redirects to `/users/sign_up` page)* on `/visitors/owner-faq` page. I want the `URL` of this page(`/visitors/owner-faq`) after signing up so that i can use it to set something like

```
if sign_up_from_url == '/visitors/owner-faq'
 @user.role = 'Owner'
end
```

I tried to use `request.referer` in the controller, but it gave me `/users/sign_up` not `/visitors/owner-faq`. However when I used `<%= url_for(:back) %>` in the **sign up view page**, it gave me `/visitors/owner-faq` which I want.But I cannot figure out how to access it in the controller. Can anyone suggest me how to access that value in controller? I'm using **Devise** for sign up.

Comment: Take a look at the [example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) at the bottom. Then, combine it with this [example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration))

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What happens is if the user is on `/visitors/owner-faq` page and clicks on the sign up link, the referrer in the sign up page is `/visitors/owner-faq`.  This is the reason why `url_for(:back)` works on that page.  Now, after submitting the form in the sign up page, the referrer is now changed to the sign up url, which makes sense.

What you want to do is save the referrer in the session when the user visits the sign up page.  So in the action that serves the sign up page (say that's the users new action)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    session[:referrer] = request.referrer
  end
end
```

So when the user submits the sign up form, you can access the session

```
def create
  referrer  = session.delete(:referrer)
  user      = User.new
  user.role = 'owner' if referrer == '/visitors/owner-faq'
  user.save!
end
```

Comment: That perfectly makes sense now. But i'm unable to find the `action` which serves the **sign up page**. The sign up page is `/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` and the path for sign up button in `/visitors/owner-faq` is `new_user_registration_url`. i didn't find any `new` action in either `registrations_controller` or `users_controller`.

Comment: you are using devise. you'd want to look into configuring the controllers https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: or always save the referrer if it is not present like the one discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058566/how-to-store-where-a-new-user-was-referred-using-rails-devise

Comment: Do you know how to get the same for `omniauth`?

Comment: won't it be the same implementation? just save the referrer always if there's nothing saved yet.  or just save the referrer in the page where you expose the links for authenticating with omniauth.

Comment: I tried the same for omniauth and failed. Here is the question i posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703209/how-to-save-the-request-referrer-for-facebook-omniauth-in-rails-4#30703396

Answer (score 2):

Even you don't have to store in session

```
if request.referrer == sign_up_from_url
  super 
end
```

This will give you last referrer before `sign_up_from_url`.