# How to save the request.referrer for facebook omniauth in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth-facebook

I have two facebook buttons in my application. One on **`users/sign_up`** and other on **`/visitors/owner-faq`**. I want to save the **`request.referrer`** in order to know from which page the user has signed up. I had implemented the same for external signup(which uses a form) and it worked. Now I'm unable to implement the same for **facebook omniauth**.

**Code:**

```
#user.rb

def self.from_omniauth(auth) 
    email         = auth.info.email 
    user          = User.find_by_email(email)   # first tries to find an existing user who signed up normal way with the same email to sign them in 
    if user && user.confirmed?                
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid      = auth.uid
      return user
    end

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|  # then tries to find the user who authenticated through FB, and if
      user.email            = auth.info.email                                # not present, creates that user
      user.password         = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name       = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name        = auth.info.last_name
      user.social_photo_url = auth.info.image
      user.skip_confirmation!   
    end
  end

#users/omniauth_callbacks_controller

def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect) 
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

#application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :store_referrer_url, :only => [:new]

  private

  def store_referrer_url
    session[:referrer] = URI(request.referer).path
  end
end
```

**Attempt #1:**

I managed to save the **`request.referrer`** like this in `users/omniauth_callbacks_controller`

```
def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    @user.referrer_url = session[:referrer] #here
    @user.save!

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect) 
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

But the problem here is the value of **`referrer_url`** is **overwritten** when the **existing user logs in from another page**. I don't want to get the **`referrer_url`** to be overwritten.

**Attempt #2:**

I tried to save the `request.referrer` in the `from_omniauth(auth)` method `User` model like this

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth) 
    email         = auth.info.email 
    user          = User.find_by_email(email)   # first tries to find an existing user who signed up normal way with the same email to sign them in 
    if user && user.confirmed?                
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid      = auth.uid
      return user
    end

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|  # then tries to find the user who authenticated through FB, and if
      user.email            = auth.info.email                                # not present, creates that user
      user.password         = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name       = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name        = auth.info.last_name
      user.social_photo_url = auth.info.image
      user.referrer_url     = session[:referrer]
      user.skip_confirmation!   
    end
  end
```

But it gave me this error

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<Class:0x0000000e1c46f8>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Comment: remove `:only => [:new]` in the application controller. you normally only want to do that in other controllers.  that's the most probable reason why you're not getting any referrer with omniauth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `referrer_url` property to stay the same after it's first set, you should use the [OR Equal](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) operator, that will only set the value if it's currently `nil` or `false`:

`@user.referrer_url ||= session[:referrer]`

If I understand correctly, your `facebook` callback is called both on sign up and login, and of course the value would be overwritten. OR Equals will prevent the value from being overwritten once it's set.

Regarding **Attempt #2**, the session hash is only available [in the controller and the view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session), so you can't use it in the model.

**Another possibility**:

You are setting `session[:referrer]` in your `store_referrer_url` method which is called in a `before_filter` callback on the `new` method.

Most likely your login  is also made with a `new` method (for example, with Devise it would be in `SessionsController`), so the callback is called again and the value is overwritten (all Devise controllers inherit from your `ApplicationController`). In this case, you could take out the `before_filter` callback out of the `ApplicationController` to the controller where you are handling signing up (would be `RegistrationsController` with Devise).

Comment: It still overwrites the `referrer_url` after changing to `session[:referrer] ||= URI(request.referer).path`

Comment: Oops, my mistake, please see the edit. Of course `session[:referrer]` would be cleared out. You can also put the `@user.referrer_url = session[:referrer]` line inside the `if @user.persisted?` and save the object again, so it won't be set on login.